# Cell-var-from-loop warning from Pylint

Tags: python, lambda, closures

For the following code:

```
for sort_key, order in query_data['sort']:
    results.sort(key=lambda k: get_from_dot_path(k, sort_key),
                 reverse=(order == -1))
```

Pylint reported an error:

> Cell variable sort_key defined in loop (cell-var-from-loop)

Could anyone give a hint what is happening here? From pylint source code the description is:

> A variable used in a closure is defined in a loop.
>   This will result in all closures using the same value for
>   the closed-over variable.

But I do not have a clue what it means. Could anyone give an example of the problem?

Comment: What kind of object is `results`? Ordinary list? Something else?

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/12423614/3001761

Comment: @Kevin e.g. results = [{key: value}, {key: value} ...]

Comment: Ok. In that case, I agree with chepner that you don't need to worry about the warning here.

Comment: The term `closure` which can be conceptually tricky made me overthink this error, which pylint has started throwing against a lot of my code. The example from the docs of code that throws this error makes it clear that this is a simple check against a basic error: https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/messages/warning/cell-var-from-loop.html#:~:text=Cell%20variable%20%25s%20defined%20in,for%20the%20closed-over%20variable. I'm disabling it in my pylintrc going forward.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

The name `sort_key` in the body of the `lambda` will be looked up when the function is actually called, so it will see the value `sort_key` had most recently. Since you are calling `sort` immediately, the value of `sort_key` will not change before the resulting function object is used, so you can safely ignore the warning. To silence it, you can make `sort_key` the default value of a parameter to the `lambda`:

```
results.sort(key=lambda k, sk=sort_key: get_from_dot_path(k, sk),
             reverse=(order == -1))
```

Comment: I'd err on the side of fixing the issue instead of ignoring the warning. If possible, I'd use `key=partial(get_from_dot_path, foo=sort_key)` instead of the lambda expression (assuming there is some parameter name `foo` defined by `get_from_dot_path` that you can use for a keyword argument; `partial` only allows filling in positional parameters exclusively from the left).

Comment: Ah I didn't realise this would fix it, I thought they were equivalent; in that case I agree.

Comment: be aware that currently the trick does not always work https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/3107

Comment: Using [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#nonlocal) did _not_ help, I had to use [partial()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) as suggested by @chepner.

Comment: Thanks. I had similar issue  ``filtered_events = list(filter(lambda x, _phase_no=phase_no: 'phase_no' in x and x['phase_no'] == _phase_no, events))``, here the phase_no was causing problem for me

Comment: This post is now linked to from [Pylint docs](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/messages/warning/cell-var-from-loop.html) :) But I don't think the `partial` trick can be used if `k` is not directly used. For example, `get_from_dot_path(2*k, sort_key)` can't be translated to `partial` directly.

Answer (score 13):

Use [functools.partial()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```py
import functools
results.sort(key=functools.partial(get_from_dot_path, foo=sort_key),
             reverse=(order == -1))
```

Comment: can confirm this not only gets rid of the warning, but really fixes the problem. Try for example making a list of lambdas print the range 1,10 - with lambdas, they all print 9, with functools.partial they print each value